# Need to timeout Get-AzureStorageBlob function

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell, azure-runbook

I am using the `Get-AzStorageBlob` command to pull out blob files
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblob?view=azps-9.2.0

I want to ignore large-size blobs as they take an eternity to process.
Do we have a way where if this command does not yield output in 10 sec should error out?

```
try{
    $blobs = ($container | Get-AzStorageBlob -context $context -ServerTimeoutPerRequest 10 -ClientTimeoutPerRequest 10).LastModified 
}
catch {write-output "$($container) timed out"}
```

I tried adding parameters `ServerTimeoutPerRequest` & `ClientTimeoutPerRequest` but they seem to not help at all as the command is not erroring out after 10 sec.

Comment: Do you need all azure blob files except large files?

Comment: Mainly I am interested in knowing most recent date anywhere in container

if there are too many blobs, I want to ignore as scripts are failing
so instead if there is container having too many blobs, intend to ignore that container and move to next container rather than script failing in between

1 work around I had, was maintain one exclusion list and include those 4-5 containers which were failing there

In the end I could complete my analysis by manually ignoring huge containers

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to skip the large files in Blob:**

This is one approach to skip the large files using PowerShell.

> Based on filesize limit condition, we can fetch the files satisfying the size limit, if any file falls under beyond this size limit will be skipped in fetching.

I have uploaded **6** Files into my blob.

[image]

**Here is the script:**

```
Connect-AzureAD
Install-Module Az.Storage
$MaxReturn = 10000
$ContainerName = "thejademo"
$Token = $Null
$StorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'venkatsa' -StorageAccountKey 'ky3ewvDbRRMKqVWD75mQXAeojowkYUQFzVSItmgVosrygIG+ITJsrGRgAlVcqo2sY0zlcU2QVNMu+AStJrzWDA=='
$Container = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name 'thejademo' -Context $StorageContext 
$Blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -MaxCount $MaxReturn  -ContinuationToken $Token -Context $StorageContext |where {($_.Length -lt 71458173)}
$Total = $Blobs.count
$Skip= "Skipped Large Blob Files"

Write-Host Total Files $Total in container $ContainerName $skip
```

**Total 6 files in my container but displayed only 4 files (skipped large files).**

[image]